# hoursBetween gives too big value as answer

Tags: java, mysql, jodatime

I really don't have an idea on what is wrong with my code. I am using Joda-Time api on this case. This code is after rs.next(), I need to get the value of hh in integer because i have to multiply it on the hourly rate of a parking service.

```
java.sql.Time timeOut = new java.sql.Time(new java.util.Date().getTime());
java.sql.Time timeIn = rs.getTime("timeIn");
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(timeOut);//Value is 18:39:24
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(timeIn);//Value is 16:03:50
int hh = Hours.hoursBetween(d1,d2).getHours();
txtDuration.setText(""+hh);//Display on textbox and shows 421946
```

also tried this

```
Duration duration = new Duration(d1,d2);
long ss = duration.getStandardSeconds();
long mm = ss/60;
long hh = mm/60;
```

Good day and Thank you in advance.

Comment: `421946` hours is a little more than 48 years. Seems like `timeIn` is actually a `16:03:50 Jan 1, 1970`.

Comment: I used CURRENT_TIME() for the Update statement with timeIn, and its data type is TIME, does that still store date by any chance? Please bare with me I'm still new with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a `Date` part in `timeIn` column in DB.

```
Hours.hoursBetween(DateTime.parse("1970-01-01T16:03:50"), DateTime.parse("2018-02-19T18:39:24")).getHours()  == 421946
```

If you would like to compare just Time (without date part), you can use `LocalTime` from joda library.

```
LocalTime d2 = new LocalTime(timeOut.getTime());
LocalTime d1 = new LocalTime(timeIn.getTime());
```

Or specify proper date:

```
d1.withDate(<put proper date here>)
```

Comment: This solves my problem, thank you so much sir.
I didn't included dates on timeIn and timeOut because I only need them to be subtracted.

Answer (score 3):

From [java.sql.Time javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html)

> The date components should be set to the "zero epoch" value of January 1, 1970 and should not be accessed.

And then, in your code

```
java.sql.Time timeOut = new java.sql.Time(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```

`new java.util.Date()` in general is not going to be January 1, 1970, so you are in fact creating an invalid `java.sql.Time` instance. What is probably happening under the hood is that you are calculating the number of hours between some moment in January 1 1970 (your `timeIn`, that is coming from the database and can be assumed to be correct) and some moment *right now*:

421946 hours = 421946 / 24 days ~ 17581 days ~ 17581 / 365 years ~ 48 years.

And 1970 + 48 = 2018, this year.

Answer (score 0):

While I don’t have experience with Joda-Time, I know the `java.time` answer:

```
    LocalTime timeOut = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Africa/Khartoum"));
    LocalTime timeIn = rs.getObject("timeIn", LocalTime.class);
    int hh = (int) ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(timeIn, timeOut);
```

Are you sure you know the time zone of the time from the database? “Now” is a very time zone sensitive concept, so you can get virtally any incorrect result if your time zones don’t match. Trusting that you do know, substitute the correct time zone if it didn’t happen to be Africa/Khartoum. Also are you sure the times are on the same day? You may try this correction:

```
    if (timeOut.isBefore(timeIn)) {
        hh += 24;
    }
```

It obviously has its limitation. It won’t work if the times are several days apart. Finally, do you know what result you want if there’s a transition to or from summer time (DST) between `timeIn` and `timeOut`?

And you thought you were the one asking the question. ;-)

Skimming through [the documentation of `org.joda.time.LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html?org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) it seems to me you could use that class in quite a similar way, constructing `timeOut` using the no-arg constructor and `timeIn` using the `LocalTime(Object instant)` constructor.